# Node.js: Converting markdown to HTML and then wrapping specific content in <section> tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, markdown

I'm using NodeJS and MarkdownJS to parse .md files into html. This is working great but now I need to wrap specific areas of my generated HTML with section tags.

Example Markdown File:

```
#This is my main header

Introduction paragraph

##Sub Section 1

blah blah blah

##Sub Section 2

blah blah blah

##Sub Section 3

blah blah blah
```

Which is parsed into the following HTML:

```
<h1>This is my main header</h1>
<p>Introduction paragraph</p>
<h2>Sub Section 1</h2>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<h2>Sub Section 2</h2>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<h2>Sub Section 3</h2>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
```

My desired output is:

```
<h1>This is my main header</h1>
<p>Introduction paragraph</p>

<section>
<h2>Sub Section 1</h2>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</section>

<section>
<h2>Sub Section 2</h2>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</section>

<section>
<h2>Sub Section 3</h2>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</section>
```

I thought I would write an algorithm to do roughly:

```
1. Parse html to find indexes of h2 tags
2. Loop through indexes
3. For first h2 tag, insert <section> in front
4. For all h2 tags except that last, insert </section><section> in front
5. For last h2 tag, insert </section>
```

Can anyone think of a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since HTML is valid Markdown, you may be able to do this before you send your text to the processor:

```
str.replace(/(##[^#]+)/g, '<section>$1</section>')
```

Of course, you will have to modify this code if you want to have other headers between `h2` tags.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRzBk/) you can play around with.