# marked: customize parser to render <h2> and following elements in <section>

Tags: markdown, javascript-marked

How to customize `marked` to make it rendering `<h2>` tags and following elements in a `<section>`. If a new `<h2>` tag appears afterwards, wrap everything in a new `<section>` again.

exmpale markdown input:

```
# h1 header

## first h2 header
paragraph
paragraph

## second h2 header
paragraph
paragraph
```

html output:

```
<h1>h1 header</h1>

<section>
  <h2>frist h2 header</h2>
  <p>paragrqph</p>
  <p>paragrqph</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>second h2 header</h2>
  <p>paragrqph</p>
  <p>paragrqph</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { marked } from 'marked'

const str = `markdown from <textarea> input`
const modifiedMarkdown = str.replace(/(##[^#]+)/g, '<section>\n\n$1</section>')
const markdownWithSections = marked.parse(modifiedMarkdown, { mangle: false, headerIds: false })
```

Based on the answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228024/node-js-converting-markdown-to-html-and-then-wrapping-specific-content-in-sect?rq=2). - added two line breaks after `section` start